# Could anyone help me with this Flash problem?

Tags: adobe-flash

I have a very frustrating problem with my flash project.
I have two scenes in my flash movie, each of them has lots of links and navigation within itself. And there is one button that takes you from one scene to another.
When I test Scene 2, everything works fine. However, when I test the whole movie, the navigation within Scene 2 won't work and there is no error!
Does anyone has any thought about what is going wrong?
I'm using Flash CS6.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very broad but the obvious thing to look at would be have you got a stop on scene1? If not it will auto run into scene2.